# Qt scene graph order

Tags: qt, qgraphicsscene, pyside2

I'm trying to implement a scene graph for a chess board.

I've built some Square QGraphicsItem objects for each chess board square that are direct child of the QGraphicsScene. And I've built some Piece that are direct child of those Square.

My scene graph looks like this:

```
Board |- Square0 - Piece0
      |- Square1 - Piece1
      |- Square2
      |- Square3 - Piece2
```

The problem with this is the stacking order of the elements: when I drag the Piece1, it will be displayed under Square2 and Square3.

How should I do to prevent this Square overlapping of Pieces ?
I tried to change Pieces zValue, but it seems that this does not work.

I like this structure, it allows me to place pieces at a fixed pos() relative to their parent and just re-parent them when they move.

Here is the code that build the scene if it helps.
ChessSquareItem and ChessPieceItem are derivated classes of QGraphicsItem.
I removed non-relevant code to ease out the reading.
This is written in Python3.6, using PySide2 (5.11.1a1.dev1530005708).

```
    # draw the board and pieces
    for square in range(64):
        square_item = ChessSquareItem(square, self.SQUARE_WIDTH)

        piece = self.board.piece_map()[square]
        # ChessPieceItem is created with square_item as parent
        ChessPieceItem(piece, square_item)

        # then the square_item is added to the QGraphicsScene
        self.addItem(square_item)
```

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: The pieces aren't part of the board, so I suggest not parenting them. You can get the centre position of a square and place the chess pieces at the relevant positions as they move around the board.